# Visual studio 2015 set all include directories for project

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I need to set the include directories for ALL of the files in a project/solution in VS 2015. Yes, this question has been answered here before, but it seems that does not work in VS 2015. If I highlight the tab for a file, and hit project->xxx properties (bottom selection) I get everything, including configuration properties->VC++ directories->include directories.

That's fine, but only fixes include issues on THAT ONE FILE. The solution, recommended various places on the internet, including here, is to use the "solution explorer" window at right, then click the solution/project, hit the little wrench or right click, and get a "property pages" dialog.

Good, but this property page is a stripped down version of the above, and has no VC++ include directories, nor VC++ include anything, nor include anything.

Perhaps this changed in 2015? How do I set this once for the entire project, instead of file by file?

Thanks,

Scott Franco

Comment: so, are you clicking on solution or on project?

Comment: As commented, I tried several methods (detailed above). I am a relative newcomer to VS, so would like to know the procedure, whatever that is, to set globally to the project/solution/whatever.